# Docker certbot trouble after relocating data-root

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

Because of my Docker images/containers filling up my root partition, I've been trying to move the `data-root` directory of my Docker installation to a different location (current: `/usr/lib/docker`; target: `/mnt/target/docker-data`). Based on some suggestions on the interwebs, it should be possible to simply `cp -r /usr/lib/docker /mnt/target/docker-data` and create a symlink `ln -s /mnt/target/docker-data /var/lib/docker` (after renaming the original `/usr/lib/docker` location.

Unfortunately, when I try this, my Nginx Proxy Manager goes haywire (I think?) and none of the docker containers can be reached over the network (502 errors when trying to access e.g. Jellyfin from my browser). Strangely, only Portainer can be accessed just fine. While monitoring `htop`, I've noticed that `certbot` keeps consuming a lot of CPU resources, and doesn't seem to settle down even after 10 minutes of 100% CPU load.

I know that these observations are a bit vague, but I currently have no idea on how to debug the issue, or what could be the root cause of it. I welcome any suggestions to further dig into it.

The exact sequence of commands I executed, for completeness:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo cp -r /var/lib/docker /mnt/target/docker-data
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bak
sudo ln -s /mnt/target/docker-data /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: For future reference: I was never able to fix this issue. I resorted to creating an empty `docker-data` directory and configured `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to point to that directory. After that I recreated all my docker containers (`docker compose` made life easy).